# Image background repeat y in the middle of site

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to repeat a "background" through my site. Must be in the middle exactly and with 100% height. Already tried the position absolute + 25% margin but when I'm zooming, the site falls apart. Any idea how can I achieve this effect?
Now I added it in the body and works well in Chrome and Safari, but not in the others.

```
<body style="background:url('sheets/image_assets/parchment.png') repeat-y 50%">
```

Oh, I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background: url(your-background-image.jpg) repeat-y 50% 0;
```

on the `body` should work in any browser.

[DEMO](http://dabblet.com/gist/3733879)

Also, try using just `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: The html tag already contains a background attribute which repeats on the y and x coordinate too.

Comment: The problem is that the body won't stretch and I can't set it's height to 100%.